# Handling multiple menu inputs java - returning to while loop in main?

Tags: java

I'm trying to design a program that has a menu and essentially for the duration of the program handles input from that menu. I have another menu that may be called by another class that may interrupt the flow of this program and call another method, which displays another menu. Is there a way to transfer this control back to the while loop inside main to continue handle the input, when the display menu is called from another class, or would it be more sensible to write this entirely differently?

The code is just an example of how this is currently being structured. Currently I've tried setting a flag when the other class wants to call displayNewMenu, and checking for this flag in the while loop, and calling it from there, but this seems not to be working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayMenu();
    while(true) {
        handleMenuInput();
}

public void displayNewMenu() {
}
```

Comment: Check '}' I thing it missed

Comment: @Jägermeister what makes you think he works with Swing JavaFX? I think he means console application.

Comment: Correct regarding console program. What I'm not calling displayNewMenu directly from another class, it is getting triggered by it. I know the question seems a little strange, rest assured it's not a real word program.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want this MENU to be accessible all the time  you will have to do some multithreading.
Otherwise you will not be able to do other work and still be able to take user input.

Create thread to handle user interaction, this will include scanner that gets user input , puts output into console and spawn threads for your work.

You cant do this in singlethreaded enviroment.You will make your program hang.

If you jsut want to go back to  handle user input/change menu etc, you need to change a flow a bit

```
       public void work1(){
         //some work
       }
      work2,3,4()...

       public void menuSelector(){
           //get input
           if(input=menu1){
             menu1();
           } ....

       }

     public void menu1(){
           displayMenu1();
           while(true){
           //get input
            if(input=work1){
               work1();
             }
            if(input=exitmenu){
               break;
           }
           }
          menuSelector();
        }

   public void menu2(){
           displayMenu2();
           while(true){
           //get input
            if(input=work2){
               work2();
             }
            if(input=exitmenu){
               break;
           }
           }
          menuSelector();
        }
```

I think you get the idea.This will allow yo ut ojump between menus , and loop within menu as well.Ofcourse odnt just use multiple if statements , switch woud be appropriete here.

Comment: Multithreading is not the issue here, I just want to be able to pass the flow of control back to the while loop in the main method to handle input when displayNewMenu is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for a multi-threaded solution, consider this approach:

```
main(){
    while(true){ // Infinite loop to ensure that the control always comes back to display the menu. Exits only when the user selects an option to quit.
        displayMenu();
        handleUserInput();
    }
}

displayMenu(){
    // Show menu options here:
    // Press 1 to perform task 1.
    // Press 2 to perform task 2.
    // Press 3 to exit.
}

handleUserInput(opt){
    if opt == 1, perform task 1
    else if opt == 2, perform task 2
    else if opt == 3, exit
    else show error "invalid input"
}

performtask1(){
    while(true){
        displayTask1Menu();
        handleTask1UserInput();
    }
}

displayTask1Menu(){
    // Show menu options here:
    // Press 1 to perform sub task 1.
    // Press 2 to perform sub task 2.
    // Press 3 to exit to main menu.
}

handleTask1UserInput(){
    if opt == 1, perform sub task 1
    else if opt == 2, perform sub task 2
    else if opt == 3, exit to main menu / break;
    else show error "invalid input"
}
```

This way the user will be prompted back to the menu after performing each operation with in sub menus.

You can also alter the menu display based on the user inputs.

Comment: I don't think is what I'm looking for either. The problem is displayMenu2() can be called which is outside of the while loop, by another class. The problem is, what is the best way to jump back into the while(true) loop to handle input when this happens.

Comment: You'll need to keep the control within the main while loop for the control to come back there.. If you get out of the loop, it's going to be hard for you to  get back there.. I've updated the pseudo code to reflect another approach that you can tan possibly take..

Comment: You will need to use a hierarchical approach where you have a
`Main menu > (sub menu 1 > sub menu 1.1, sub menu 1.2), (sub menu 2 > sub menu 2.1, sub menu 2.2),...`

Comment: There has to be some method that needs to call the `OtherClass` which calls `displayMenu2()`. How does the `OtherClass` get control first of all? Some one will have to invoke it? So whoever is doing that will have to do that inside this while loop.

Comment: It's a distributed application, so when an event happens, displayMenu2() is triggered from the other class who is responsible for publishing events for the console application to handle. Invoking it inside the main loop of the console application is not possible

Comment: Ah! In that case, Wouldn't it be a multi threaded environment? If so, you're right, we'll need an alternate approach. Based on your earlier comment `Correct regarding console program.`, I thought it was a single-threaded console application.

Comment: I suppose it could be multithreaded, but where would you start the additional threads, and what is happening in the main thread?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108510/discussion-between-user3601148-and-anacron).